# Cant remove the decimal places in textbox SSRS

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

I'm working with SSRS Report that display the grades of Students. I need to display the grades which are already rounded to the nearest integer and I'm ok with that. But I'm wondering why the decimal places still appears even if the grades is already rounded and I already set the textbox properties to 0 decimal places. I've notice that it was started when I used cast. What is the problem? I need to cast the grades because of my condition. Please see below sql syntax and images.

I used MSSQL Server 2008 and Report Builder 3.0 r2

Here's my sql syntax in getting the grades of student

```
,(CASE 
 when  dtl.STUDENT_GRADE < 1 or  dtl.STUDENT_GRADE is null Then '-' Else  
 CAST(dtl.STUDENT_GRADE AS nvarchar(20))end) as GRADE
```

This is the report looks like and my settings in text box . Please see image

[image: report]
[image: textbox properties]

Comment: Your report getting `nvarchar` field not numeric. Try to convert `dtl.STUDENT_GRADE` to int before converting to `varchar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem, Since the cast gives me an issue with the decimal places, I changed the condition to set the grades of student to 0 if the grades is NULL or less than 1. Then I set the text box properties to show (-) if the value is 0.

Thanks for all your help it gives me an idea to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the Category to "Custom" and then set "Custom format" to `N0`

[image]

Comment: it returns me the original value of grades. Ex. 90.750.